# denormalization many to many relationship Hbase

Tags: database, hadoop, hbase, hdfs, denormalization

Currently I'm working on platform for product rating and our database is Hbase which I'm new on it. I have RDBMS data with designing

[image]

User can create many list ,where every list have one/many product. 
As denormalization for user table both list and list details should store in onetable.

 
is possible to user table has  composite column qualifier for list colunm  fimaly like :

> List:listID_productid:value

Comment: yes, you can have such a composite column qualifiers but the char ':' is reserved to separate Column Family and Column Qualifier so  use another separator for the value

Comment: @harold thank. you but I wonder if this way of key composite can be efficiency for future retrieving data. due that Hbase no support SQL too?

Comment: Hi @gharibeh. I'm not sure to undertand your point. HBase does not support SQL; if you need SQL, use Phoenix.  To retrieve data, you'll have to write for instance a small Web Service that converts your denormalized data to a JSON structure.